# How to rotate a treap or AVL-tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

Sorry to bother you guys again, but I have a question and i haven't figured it out on my own for several days.
It is about the rotation of a treap, for example, to right rotate a treap at pos.
The question is how to link (or connect) `pos->left` to `pos`'s original parent? 
I found this code online, which works, but i didn't see how it solves my question, is it because of the use of `*&`? If so, could you help me explain it a little bit?
And what is the function of `pos=b` is this code?

```
void Treap::right_rotate(Node *&pos) {
    Node *b   = pos->left; 
    pos->left = b->right;
    b->right  = pos;
    pos       = b;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where did you find the code, btw?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tricky part is indeed the `*&` part. That declares it as a reference to a pointer (here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sf8shae%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer#4) to some similar sample code, but I fear they may be more confusing than helpful).

By changing out the node to which the pointer points with `pos = b`, you can swap the contents to the different node without having to know the parent. The original reference is updated to be the new rotated node.

Here's a diagram just in case you needed a little overkill of what the rotation looks like (though it sounds like you understand that part).

Initial condition:

```
Node *&pos; 

         |
        [P]
      /     \
     L       R
    / \     / \ 
   w   x   y   z
```

You then store the left child since you are about to overwrite it as far as P is concerned.

```
Node *b = pos->left;
pos->left = b->right;

           |
    L     [P]
  /  \   /   \
 w     x      R
             / \ 
            y   z
```

Now we finish the rotation since since L is floating in space, breaking proper tree structure:

```
b->right = pos;

        L     
      /  \ |
     w    [P]
         /   \
        x     R
             / \ 
            y   z
```

We then finish the upkeep by updating the reference to the node pointer to be the new node that replaces the contents of that place in memory:

```
pos = b;

       |
      [L]     
     /   \
    w      P
         /   \
        x     R
             / \ 
            y   z
```

Whomever was previously pointing to `pos` (`pos`'s original parent) now points to the same spot in memory, but that value has now been replaced with the child that has been rotated.